# Samsung Series 7 Chronos Ubuntu HDMI external display support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hdmi

Does connecting external display to Samsung Series 7 Chronos laptop via HDMI port work on Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, but you can always try with an Ubuntu Live CD.

Comment: I'm looking for new laptop & eg [Dell XPS 15z](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z) has problems with HDMI. I'd like some Samsung owner to confirm my question before I'll buy the laptop.

Comment: I'm not sure about HDMI support on this particular laptop, but in general, HDMI is one of the better-standardized protocols, and I have yet to see any problems under various (recent) Linuxen.

Comment: Well did you actually try doing it?

Comment: No, as I said earlier, I don't own this Samsung laptop - I intend to buy it. That's why I'm looking for someone who actually owns it to answer my question.

Comment: Have you tried looking up reviews? Going on YouTube?

Comment: Yeah, didn't find info about hdmi+ubuntu in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I've got the info from a guy who owns this laptop:

> As long as you do not boot up with the HDMI connected it works. Boot up, log in then connect HDMI and everything works. I've been using it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

All Samsung Series 7 notebooks use an ATI Radeon HD 6xxx series GPU. The drivers for these are [supported on Linux,](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) and you should have no issues with running a second monitor from it. The cards are also supported by the open source `xserver-xorg-video-ati`

Some of these are Hybrid graphics, so you can switch between the integrated and dedicated. Intel graphics should provide no issues.

Comment: I've read that people actually disable ATI card & use integrated Intel, due to [some](http://superuser.com/questions/355836/compatibility-of-linux-with-samsung-series-7-chronos) [problems](http://schibum.blogspot.com/2011/11/ubuntu-oneiric-on-samsung-series-7.html) with the drivers...

Comment: @adrian It has hybrid graphics, you can swap in between them. You should have no problem using the intel drivers either