# Samsung series 7 Chronos fan runs constantly on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, fan, ubuntu-11.10

First off, I'm a Linux Noob - I successfully installed it on an older laptop, so I went out and bought this Samsung series 7.  After dual booting Ubuntu alongside Windows I noticed the fan would constantly run on Linux and Windows.  However, if I turned the 'Silent Mode' (fn + F11) ON on Windows it'd stop running, unless necessary.  The only problem is this 'Silent Mode' function doesn't work on Ubuntu.

So, I scoured the web looking for a solution.  I found a few sites with people discussing something similar but no solutions arose.  I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction..

Here's a couple resources I found, not sure if they will help you, help me..

https://bugs.launchpad.net/samsung-tools/+bug/884686

http://linuxtweaking.blogspot.com/2011/02/linux-kernel-will-soon-provide-better.html

[Compatibility of Linux with Samsung series 7 Chronos](https://superuser.com/questions/355836/compatibility-of-linux-with-samsung-series-7-chronos/384679#384679)

There must be other people out there having this problem.  It's a great computer, it's just a little annoying having the fun run all the time.  I would really appreciate any help or guidance on this issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These may help you out:

ATI/AMD Graphics Drivers:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Linux on my Samsung project:

http://www.voria.org/forum/

https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa