# Battery life Samsung Series 7 with Linux (Mint, KDE)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, battery, battery-life

I've been trying all the tricks I can find to reduce power usage on my Samsung series 7 (Ivy Bridge Core i7, AMD Radeon HD 8570M GPU) laptop (running Linux Mint Olivia, KDE version), but it all seems hopeless. No matter what I do, idle power usage is about 13W (which, at least, is better than the 28W reported in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/355836/compatibility-of-linux-with-samsung-series-7-chronos) two year old topic). Even turning off the ethernet port, which was reported to use 2W, didn't change the idle power usage. Most tweaks I do don't actually change the power usage reported by the battery, even though the item in question does disappear from Powertop's list.

Plus, it would seem the actual culprit of the power use is not visble in Powertop's list. Currently, it says:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 13.8 W
The estimated remaining time is 3 hours, 7 minutes

Summary: 431,0 wakeups/second,  43,3 GPU ops/seconds, 0,0 VFS ops/sec and 13,1% CPU use

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  8.23 W     41,1%                      Device         Display backlight
  4.23 W     41,1%                      Device         Display backlight
  2.14 W      0,0 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: eth0 (r8169)
  440 mW     15,3 ms/s     120,1        Process        kwin
  402 mW     53,9 ms/s     186,6        Process        /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 22.5 mW      2,0 ms/s      34,1        Interrupt      [46] i915@pci:0000:00:02.0
 22.5 mW    625,7 µs/s      34,0        kWork          od_dbs_timer
 15.3 mW      1,9 ms/s      23,1        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
```

That is 12.4 W for the backlight, of 13.8W. That is just not correct. And, even tot top 3 items alone are 14.5, which is *more* than 13.8.

With 13 W, a 57 Watt*hour battery would last 4.3 hour, which is what Powertop says as well, and it is about right. To get the claimed 7 hours that Windows gets, power usage needs to go down to about 8 Watt. Is that even remotely possible with Linux?

Should I just give up?

Comment: With Linux mint 16, it was a lot worse. I enabled radeon power management as outlined [here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQyNDE). Now power use is back to about 13-14W. I read somewhere (don't remember where) that kernel 3.12 is a lot beter in terms of power management.